# How do I tweak how VSCode format JavaScript?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I make Visual Studio Code insert a space after the function keyword, when I autoformat a JavaScript file with Alt+Shift+F?

```js
// How I would like it:
var f = function (a) { ... }

// How VSCode is formatting by default:
var f = function(a) { ... }
```

I would assume this is possible placing a file in ~/.vscode/extensions/javascript, possibly by making a copy of VSCode's JavaScript.tmLanguage file and making a small change in it, but that's as far as I have gotten for now.

Comment: From my preliminary investigation it seems as though it can't be done... yet... https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7756212-format-beautify-source-code?page=2&per_page=20

Comment: It seems that the JavaScript language service is to be changed this month (January) from TypeScript to Salsa https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/release-notes/latest.md

Comment: I don't believe this is possible at the moment, but the feature request is being tracked: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1533

Comment: Thanks, @MattBierner. It seems this ticket has actually just been fixed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VS Code's built-in JS/TS formatter, this is controlled by:

- `"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": true`
- `"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": true`

These are the default values.